# Can't add SVN repository in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm trying to add an SVN repository to Eclipse.

I've installed Subclipse, and it seems to be working fine. But, when I try to "add a new SVN repository", I input this:

http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror

and I get this:

```
Error validating location: "org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed svn: unable to connect to a repository at url 'svn..'
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror': could not connect to server  'alfresco.com' Keep location anyway?
```

I've checked it in both browsers(on computer and internal eclipse br) - both works

What is the decision?

Comment: I've Installed SVN Client Adapter, SVNKit Adapter, and SVNKit Library - still not working

Comment: and also i've tried this one: Window > Preference > Team > SVN: select SVNKit (Pure Java) instead JavaHL(JNI)
and i got the message: "Error validating location: 'org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed' Keep location anyway?"

Comment: I've edited this file (server) like:
http-proxy-host = 192.168.10.89
http-proxy-port = 3128
still nothing
in eclipse>Window>>Prefr>General>NetworkCOnections i got Native Active Provider - i've tried manual and direct - nothing
maybe i'm doing smth wrong 'cause i din't really understand evrth about  proxy?

Answer (score 3):

*Did you configure Subclipse to work with your proxy server?* I'm asking because you specify this error in the second comment: `svn: E170001: HTTP proxy authorization failed`.

To make sure that proxy settings are correct, check the `servers` file on the CLIENT
machine. The file is located in `.subversion` directory in the user's home directory on Linux systems and in `%APPDATA%\Subversion` on Windows systems. Configurable options you are interested in are:

```
http-proxy-exceptions
http-proxy-host
http-proxy-port
http-proxy-username
```

If you don't have any proxy server but these options are still configured, then remove them. Otherwise, make sure that these settings are valid. See [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers).

Comment: I've edited this file (server) like:
http-proxy-host = 192.168.10.89
http-proxy-port = 3128
still nothing
in eclipse>Window>>Prefr>General>NetworkCOnections i got Native Active Provider - i've tried manual and direct - nothing
maybe i'm doing smth wrong 'cause i din't really understand evrth about  proxy?

Comment: @vald just update your original question with more info. No need to put such info as a comment.

Comment: Oh i've also changed Window>>Prefr>Team>Svn Client back to JavaHL and it worked! ooooh i'm soooo happy!!!

Comment: I updated my proxy pass on "server" file (without any extension) inside AppData\Roaming\Subversion and my SVN works again. Thank you!